# Embedding PDF in Chromium with Evince 3 and mozplugger

Tags: 11.10, unity, chromium, pdf, evince

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Chromium to show PDFs using Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163176/how-do-i-get-chromium-to-show-pdfs-using-evince)

Does anyone accomplished that? I can't get it working, evince opens in it's own window.
I'm using Ubuntu **11.10** with **Unity**, Chromium 16, evince 3.2.1, mozplugger 1.14.3-4
mozplugger config for pdfs is:

```
repeat noisy needs_xembed swallow(evince) fill: evince -w "$file"
```

This works just fine in Gentoo with same chromium version but evince 2(gtk2) and gnome2. So does anyone got it working or knows what prevents to.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163176/how-do-i-get-chromium-to-show-pdfs-using-evince