# How do I get Chromium to show PDFs using Evince?

Tags: chromium, evince

Is there any way to get Chromium to use a mozpluggerrc/evince combination to show PDFs embedded into its own window? Right now, Chromium is just downloading PDFs. I can open them in an external evince window by clicking on the downloaded file.

I am using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 under Ubuntu 12.04 (amd64).
Here's the pdf section of my /etc/mozpluggerrc.d/62-documents.conf:

```
application/pdf:pdf:PDF file
application/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill needs_xembed: evince "$file"
```

mozpluggerrc does show up in about:plugins.

BTW, this works just fine in Firefox.

Note: I am not looking for hints on how to use Google Chrome's PDF plugin in Chromium.

Comment: Just one other thing: about:plugins also correctly lists the application/pdf, application/x-pdf, text/pdf, and text/x-pdf mimetypes in the mozplugger section.

Comment: Okay, that gets me one step further. Now chromium opens the PDF in an external evince window. Is there any way to get this working as an embedded evince?

BTW, the EVINCE() macro is defined as follows in both /etc/mozpluggerrc and /etc/mozpluggerrc.d/40-global_defs.conf:

    define(EVINCE, [repeat swallow(evince) fill needs_xembed: evince "$file"])

Comment: That line is already there (see my comment above) and doesn't change anything. I played around with the parameters, but so far haven't found anything that changes the behavior.

Comment: Please put all this information in your question instead of buried in the comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `/etc/mozpluggerrc.d` edit the `40-global_defs.conf` and add

```
### Evince
define(EVINCE, [repeat swallow(evince) fill needs_xembed: evince "$file"])
```

Now in  `/etc/mozpluggerrc.d/62-documents.conf` , the **GV()** & **ACROREAD()** *(not necessary though)* needs to be replaced with **EVINCE()** as

```
application/pdf:pdf:PDF file
application/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/pdf:pdf:PDF file
text/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
```

> EVINCE() << previously ACROREAD()

```
    repeat noisy swallow(Xpdf) fill needs_xembed: xpdf -g +9000+9000 "$file"
    repeat noisy swallow(okular) fill needs_xembed: okular "$file"
        repeat noisy swallow(epdfview) fill needs_xembed: epdfview "$file"
```

> EVINCE() << previously GV()

```
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill needs_xembed: evince "$file"
```

Save and try opening PDF files in Chromium , it will open with evince.

[Thanks to this Original Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10358713)